# Google Forms Booking

Tags: google-apps-script

Our spreadsheet only has 2 columns for data to match students with tutors. The first column is student information. The second has "yes" or "no" for availability with a tutor. We want it so that after students have been selected from the Google Form by a tutor, they are marked "No" on the sheet and their information removed from the Form options:

```
function updateCHECKBOX() {
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const studentsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Students")
const students =studentsSheet.getRange(2,1,studentsSheet.getLastRow(),1).getDisplayValues()

const studentsList = students.filter(row=>row[1]=="YES").map(row => row[0])

const form = FormApp.openById("1FvM3v3Cg1b2lSRTJpp3V_pl369wkJoAS7ypO0J4AhQg")
const studentsQuestion = form.getItemById ("2116012197")
studentsQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(studentsList)
}
```

However, when we run the final code, we get "Error, Exception: Array is empty: values". Images of the sheet and form are below:

["Students" sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVKQN.png)

[Google form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD8tX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have two columns of data

The perhaps this:

```
const datesList = dates.filter(row=>row[2]=="FREE").map(row => row[0])
```

should be this:

```
const datesList = dates.filter(row=>row[1]=="FREE").map(row => row[0])
```

I would have to see the spreadsheet and more of the code to be sure.

It should be fairly simple to figure out which rows to want to keep?

Comment: Hi! We have posted more information in the question now. Please let us know if this changes anything. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to fix it. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I might have done is create another tab/cell and use a filter() function to filter out A2:A if ColB is "N0". Btw, I noticed you left out .asListItem(); after your form.getItemById ("2116012197").

**Google Sheets**

Assuming you dump the filtered data into Col C

`=filter(A2:A,B2:B = "NO")`

**Apps Script**

```
function updateCHECKBOX() {
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const studentsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Students");
const form = FormApp.openById("1FvM3v3Cg1b2lSRTJpp3V_pl369wkJoAS7ypO0J4AhQg");
const studentsQuestion = form.getItemById ("2116012197").asListItem();

//Updates for Info
  var infoValues = studentsSheet.getRange(2, 3,tab.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues(); // Where to start grabbing values? use 2 to skip the header row and identify the column. Currently taking from ColC which is the filtered info
  var info = []; // Set an empty array
  for(var i = 0; i < infoValues.length; i++) // Set values into the array, ignore empty cells
    if(infoValues[i][0] != "")
      info[i] = infoValues[i][0];

 infolist.setChoiceValues(info); // populate the drop-down with the array data
}
```

Comment: This is how I create a dynamic update between sheets <> form. Try out what I have suggested and let me know if it doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you for the input! We actually figured out our errors. Thank you again for your time! Really helping us novices out :-)

Comment: Oh what was the error made if you don't mind sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function updateMultipleChoices() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const studentsSheet = ws.getSheetByName("Students");
  const students = studentsSheet.getRange(1, 1, studentsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  const choices = students.filter(r => r[1] == "YES").map(r => r[0]);
  const form = FormApp.openById("1FvM3v3Cg1b2lSRTJpp3V_pl369wkJoAS7ypO0J4AhQg");
  const studentsQuestion = form.getItemById("2116012197");
  studentsQuestion.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices);
}
```